# UINavigationBar bottom border disappears

Tags: ios, swift, overriding, uinavigationbar, draw

I'm subclassing `UINavigationBar`, and in interface builder I use the Identity Inspector to set this as the class of the `NavigationBar` of my `UINavigationController`. the problem is, when I override the draw method, the bottom border of my `navigationBar` disappears. This is my code:

```
class YC_NavigationBar: UINavigationBar {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "TopBar_Button_Back")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        self.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "TopBar_Button_Back")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(0, -200.0), for: .default)

    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        for i in self.subviews {
            if NSStringFromClass(i.classForCoder) == "_UINavigationBarContentView" {
                for j in i.subviews {
                    for constraint in j.constraints {
                        if constraint.firstAttribute == .leading && NSStringFromClass(constraint.firstItem!.classForCoder) == "_UIModernBarButton"  {
                            constraint.constant = 0
                            break
                        }
                    }
                    if NSStringFromClass(j.classForCoder) == "_UIButtonBarStackView" {
                        let ctr = NSLayoutConstraint(item: j, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: i, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                        i.addConstraint(ctr)
                    }
                }
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's so ridiculous that's happening by just overriding that method. How Can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two main options here:

1. Draw a line yourself like so:

   ```
   override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
       super.draw(rect)

       // your other code here.

       if rect.maxY == self.bounds.maxY {
           if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
               context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
               context.setLineWidth(1)
               context.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height))
               context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width, y: bounds.height))
               context.strokePath()
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add a subview 1px height to the bar in the Interface Builder.

P.S. Don't do a layouting code in a `drawRect()` method. There's a specific overriding point exists exactly for that purpose:

```
open func layoutSubviews() // override point. called by layoutIfNeeded automatically. As of iOS 6.0, when constraints-based layout is used the base implementation applies the constraints-based layout, otherwise it does nothing.


    /* -layoutMargins returns a set of insets from the edge of the view's bounds that denote a default spacing for laying out content.
     If preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins is YES, margins cascade down the view tree, adjusting for geometry offsets, so that setting
     the left value of layoutMargins on a superview will affect the left value of layoutMargins for subviews positioned close to the
     left edge of their superview's bounds
       If your view subclass uses layoutMargins in its layout or drawing, override -layoutMarginsDidChange in order to refresh your 
     view if the margins change.
       On iOS 11.0 and later, please support both user interface layout directions by setting the directionalLayoutMargins property
     instead of the layoutMargins property. After setting the directionalLayoutMargins property, the values in the left and right
     fields of the layoutMargins property will depend on the user interface layout direction.
     */
```

Comment: I tried adding a subview with 1px height, but my app freezes on splash screen.
but using layoutSubview method solved my problem. Thank you so much for your help